# Questionnaire regarding the motivation to be physically active

Tags: measurement, motivation, exercise

Does anyone know a questionnaire regarding the motivation to be physically active? That is, the motivation to move more (i.e. walk, cycle, run) and sit less on a daily basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[David Markland's website](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/%7Epes004/exercise_motivation/scales.htm) has several related questionnaires and scales that are available for research use. The *Behavioural Regulation in Exercise Questionnaire* seems like a good fit:

> *The Behavioural Regulation in Exercise Questionnaire* (BREQ) measures different forms of motivation for exercise based on Deci and Ryan's (1985, 1991) continuum conception of extrinsic and intrinsic motivation.

There are several other related instruments also available on the same website:

> *The Exercise Motivations Inventory-2* (EMI-2) is a measure of participation motives or reasons for exercising. *The Exercise Motives and Gains Inventory* (EMGI) is a recent development that complements the EMI-2 to provide scales assessing perceived gains from exercise that correspond to the EMI-2 scales.
>
> *The Perceived Environmental Supportiveness Scale* measures perceptions of the extent to which exercise professionals provide individuals with support for their psychological needs (i.e., autonomy support, structure and involvement).
>
> *The Exercise Causality Orientations Scale* (ECOS) measures individual differences in the tendency to be autonomous, controlled or amotivated in exercise contexts and is derived from Deci and Ryan's Causality Orientations Theory.
>
> *The Locus of Causality for Exercise Scale* is a short measure of the degree to which individuals feel self-determined with respect to exercise.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and informative response!

I would like to identify changes in motivation to get physically active using a self-report technique (i.e. as a manipulation check). That is, physical activity in moving more (e.g. walking, running, cycling) and sitting less, not necessarily vigorous exercise.These questionnaires are indeed very helpful, but perhaps with a too big of focus on "exercise", instead of "physical activity".